How to display Talend tDbRow output?
I have to output the result of the query in tDbRow, here "show datestyle;" in a Postgresql database as an example.
What i did :


And now, how do i display the output object ?
Sadly, the globalMap.get("tDBRow_1_QUERY") only shows the query.

Connect a tLogRow  to the output of the tDBRow component.

Yes, @RealHowTo i did and have this object display not the readable message :
2024-09-06 10:45:54|INFO |dbrow|tWarn_1|DB'sConnected org.postgresql.jdbc.PgResultSet@42e26948

Try with SELECT current_setting('DateStyle');  and make sure that your column in the schema  is a String

DbRow stills deliver an object output format that is not usable directly in a LogRow
Cannot convert from resultset to a String

Ahh ... the tdbrow component is used with SQL with no output (like CREATE TABLE or INSERT). In your case, you want to use tdbinput component instead.

Yes, in this query it could be possible to run it in tDbInput, but as you see, there is a checkbow allowing an output in tDbRow. It means that there is a possibility to display it. That's what i'm searching How to.

Ok found it :

dbRow sould output an object variable
use of tParseRecordSet as describe in screenshot : create an attribute line with value in position 1
display the value with tLogRow


Below : result of Show datestyle;

